# InternalServerError when using GetLanguageNames from the Microsoft Translate Service

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, language-translation

I am developing a wrapper for the Microsoft Cognitive Translation Services API, and using RestSharp as my main driver.

So far, I've implemented /Translate and /GetLanguagesForTranslate (which return language codes) but I met a wall when trying to implement **/GetLanguageNames**
Here is the offending piece of code:

```
    public void EnrichCodesWithNames(IEnumerable<Language> languageCodes)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("appid", _tokenRefresher.BearerToken);         
        request.AddParameter("locale", "nb-NO");
        request.AddParameter("languageCodes", string.Join(",", languageCodes.Where(c => !c.Code.Contains("-")).Select(c => c.Code).ToArray()));            

        var result = _restClientTranslation.Execute(request);
        if(result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var element = result.Content;
        }
    }
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_GetLanguageNames), I need to specify **locale** as a two-letter lowercase string and an ISO 3166 two-letter uppercase subculture code. I am assuming 'nb-NO' would be correct? (I've also tried 'no-NB'). The documentation does not specify dash, comma or anything else, so It's quite unclear.

The second thing is the language codes themselves. Documentation states I should provide an string-array of language codes, and I'm inserting the values I obtained when calling **/GetLanguagesForTranslate**

The result is a 200 OK, however, I get an **Internal Server Error** with the following message:

*The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the server logs for more details.*

I am at a loss for what could be wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you can show the actual REST request and response data so that we aren't guessing at things such as the 'languageCodes' parameter value you are using, the URL, etc.

Comment: Also, do you reproduce the problem using the web testing console, or just in your code?

Comment: The internal server error and text written in italics is all I am getting back. So far, most of the other Methods have been implemented without any hiccups. There is no more than that XML With Internal Server error, and then a sub-node With the error. It asks me to look at the server logs, which of course, I have no Access to

Answer (score -1):

Does this help? Here's an example of calling `GetLanguageNames` and `GetLanguagesForTranslate` using `curl`.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v1/http.svc/GetLanguageNames

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate
```

The Bearer token above was obtained and made it into an environment variable using:

```
curl -k --data "" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<your key>" > Bearer.txt
set /p Bearer= < Bearer.txt
```

Always use `curl` to prototype API calls before coding. It simplifies the learning curve.

Comment: not helpful. I already have several methods implemented using bearer tokens. I do get a 200 OK, however the content of the message displays InternalServerError

Comment: Also, the example you provided is from the v1 of the API. I have a link to the current version documentation in my OP

Comment: No. You're using v1 of the API, which is going out of commission. The correct URL to use is this: https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc, which in the documentation states you should be using a POST request with designated parameters. Your example could not possibly work. a GET request to this url wil simply return the home page for translator. Here's teh documentation: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_GetLanguageNames